# How to update the core data when moved the rows from one index to another?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Data is not updating when using CoreData with tableview.
Entity Name: Device

Attributes: text1,text2,text3

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    _devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchrequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
     }



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

    if (fromIndexPath != toIndexPath ) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
        _devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchrequest error:nil]mutableCopy];

        NSManagedObjectModel *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
        NSManagedObjectModel *device2 = [self.devices objectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
        NSString *carMake = [device valueForKey:@"text1"];
        NSString *carModel = [device valueForKey:@"text2"];
        NSString *carYear = [device valueForKey:@"text3"];


        NSString *carMake1 = [device2 valueForKey:@"text1"];
        NSString *carModel1 = [device2 valueForKey:@"text2"];
        NSString *carYear1 = [device2 valueForKey:@"text3"];

        [device setValue:carMake1 forKey:@"text1"];
        [device setValue:carModel1 forKey:@"text2"];
        [device setValue:carYear1 forKey:@"text3"];

        [device2 setValue:carMake forKey:@"text1"];
        [device2 setValue:carModel forKey:@"text2"];
        [device2 setValue:carYear forKey:@"text3"]; 

    }

}
```

Database is not updating when setting new values in sqlite with CoreData. Like not updating the database.

Comment: Are you saving your managed contex?

Comment: I am exchanging the values stored in Coredata when user moves the row in tableview and value is not getting updated.

Comment: Do you have anything like sorting order of the records?

Comment: Actually, I am following this tutorial. So, now i am trying to update the rows with database as well but not working as expected.
http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/